Abort S3TransferManager downloads - AWS SDK 2
Is there a way to effectively cancel or abort an on going download from the AWS Java SDK v2 S3TransferManager? Looks like there are a few ways to pause and resume downloads, but no way to abort the download entirely. (?)
Context: SpringBoot application downloading data from S3 to on-prem using the AWS Java SDK v2 with the S3TransferManager configured with multipart transfers using an S3AsyncClient with temporal credentials.
Need: I need to be able to cancel certain downloads that are taking more time than a give threshold.

Client configuration

 SdkAsyncHttpClient httpClient = AwsCrtAsyncHttpClient.builder()                 
         .maxConcurrency(s3ClientMaxConnections)                                 
         .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectionTimeOut))                
         .connectionMaxIdleTime(Duration.ofMillis(socketTimeOut))                
         .build();                                                               
                                                                                 
 KeyGeneratorResponse keys = objectMapper.readValue(                             
         restResponse.getResponseData().get(),                                   
         KeyGeneratorResponse.class);                                            
                                                                                 
 StaticCredentialsProvider staticCredentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider 
         .create(AwsSessionCredentials.create(keys.getAccessKey(),               
                 keys.getSecretKey(), keys.getSessionToken()));                  
                                                                                 
 MultipartConfiguration multipartConfiguration = MultipartConfiguration          
         .builder().thresholdInBytes(this.multipartThreshold)                    
         .minimumPartSizeInBytes(this.minimumUploadPartSize).build();            
                                                                                 
 S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.builder()                           
         .httpClient(httpClient).multipartEnabled(true)                          
         .multipartConfiguration(multipartConfiguration)                         
         .region(Region.of(region))                                              
         .credentialsProvider(staticCredentialsProvider)                         
         .multipartEnabled(true).build(); 

......
.....

this.transferManager = S3TransferManager.builder().s3Client(this.s3Client)          
        .executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.transferManagerThreadPoolSize)) 
        .build();                                                                                                          
                                                                                 


Download code:

            DownloadFileRequest downloadFileRequest = DownloadFileRequest.builder()
                    .addTransferListener(LoggingTransferListener.create())
                    .getObjectRequest(req -> req.bucket(bucket).key(key)).destination(localFile)
                    .build();

            FileDownload download = s3Config.getTransferManager().downloadFile(downloadFileRequest);
            CompletedFileDownload downloadResult = download.completionFuture().join();

